# How to implement LIBSVM Matlab interface?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am having problem with implementing LibSVM to MATLAB. I downloaded LibSVM package, libsvm-3.14 to my Windows 7 PC and tried to implement it, but I got this message: 
"No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. For a list of supported compilers, see
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html

If make.m fails, please check README about detailed instructions."

The problem is yet not solved even after downloading the folder from this website: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#matlab Is there another site where I could download that?

Comment: Do you have a compiler already installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I am using libsvm from the site you mentioned - no problems.

Sounds like you don't have the Windows SDK installed.
You can install it from the link at http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html

Another possibility is that you don't have mex setup.
You can check using mex.getCompilerConfigurations()
If not run: mex -setup
You might also need to install a c++ compiler - there is a link to get VC2010 expressed om the web page above.

Comment: Thank's for your attention! I have installed the c++ compiler and now I get this message when I try to implement libsvm:   Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express requires the Microsoft Windows 
         Software Development Kit (SDK), but the SDK cannot be found.  
         For more information about the required SDK, see:  
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html 

I have tryed to install Windows SDK about 10 times, but It's not getting successful!! It's failing every time!! I don't have any idea of what I'm doing wrong now!!

Comment: It would probably be best to ask a new question about that.